# Newest badge details is overlay on navbar

Tags: bug, design, popup

On user's page the newest badge details and next badge details will overlay navbar while on scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Cross-site duplication in [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299121/312043)

Comment: How is this a bug? You *want* a pop-up dialog to be on top of everything else.

Comment: Actually we expect Navbar be on top of everything. @Cody Gray

Comment: popup have more priority than navbar @perumalN

Comment: Yeah i accept this...@ Sagar V